# Can't find error log I'm looking for (PayPal IPN HTTP 500)

Tags: apache2, error-handling

My site is hosted on Ubuntu 18.

The PayPal is sending a IPN (Instant Payment Notifications) to our server, sometimes successfully, but sometimes they get a HTTP 500 error, and the IPN message is not delivered to our site (although they retry to deliver it 16 times)

---

PayPal support suggested me to take a look at my error logs, but I can't find anything relevant:

**error.log** - When I check the /var/log/apache2/error.log, I only see few today's entries, but none of them is from PayPal, or have anything to do with IPN. Why do I see only today entires and why the PayPal errors are not here? As I understand, this is the error log file where they should be registered.

**access.log** - when I check /var/log/apache2/access.log, I do see there was HTTP 500 error occurred, but there is no more info about it:
`173.0.81.1 - - [31/Oct/2019:11:11:42 +0000] "POST /paypal/ipn/ HTTP/1.1" 500 3915 "-" "PayPal IPN ( https://www.paypal.com/ipn )"`

**syslog** - same thing as error.log, only today's entries and nothing related to PayPal or IPN.

**other error log files** - nothing related to PayPal or IPN.

Can someone assume what is happening here? Thanks

Comment: You can try to create a fake IPN notification (say, with `curl`) and check how your server behaves when it receives the POST.

Comment: What exactly is stored on your server at `/paypal/ipn`? There must be some software there that fails, and perhaps keeps its own logs.

Comment: Eduardo, thanks for the comment. I will try to simulate a request, that's my next plan - not with `curl` but with PayPal IPN simulator, but I still didn't do that because I have some limitations that are making this a bit difficult to do. So actually, yes, maybe a `curl` request is maybe even a better idea.

Jos, I didn't find `/paypal/ipn` folder on the server. But maybe it's some kind of redirection happening here, because more than a half of requests are actually successful, and the `ipn.php` file is on the server, but on different path `/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model`